# SQLite to WPF in MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, sqlite, mvvm, observablecollection

I am starting a project from scratch in WPF using SQLite.I want to use the latest technologies and best practices and want to use MVVM pattern.

what is the best way to start with?

Using Linq to SQL
Any other ORM
or using datatable to List collection and observable collection?

and also how can I update/delete data from SQLite if I use Observable collection?

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned best practice, why don't you write unit tests first. It will also help you think abstract.

In addition I would use entity framework rather than linq-to-sql.

Comment: Thank you david.After your reply I searched some of the articles, i found that L2S is better for smaller database/App than EF.Any pointers if you have hands on L2S and EF?Any idea how can I use sqllite to linq2 SQl-or EF?

Comment: As far as I've read L2S is no longer activly developed although some fixes may come out for it in framework updates. The main focus for development is on EF and I highly recomend using it as that would be the latest technology microsoft has for ORM.

Comment: @Dotnet Use google. There are so many tutorials and blogs about what you are asking. And according to my experience, if you relatively have a small project, you may not need MVVM nor database.